# jQuery ui tooltip with content function (url from data attribute)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I can't figure out how to make my tooltips work (jQuery UI tooltip), using a function for the `content` option.

I used [these examples from tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_tooltip.htm) as a starting point, which work for me; one of them I saved as a file, called by the browser without a server, which worked as well.  But there is no example for the `content` option being a function, so I tried myself.

This is what I currently have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Tooltip functionality</title>
      <base url="." target="_self">
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).tooltip({
                items: '.tooltip',  // a CSS selector, right?
                content: function(callback) {
                    var tooltip_url = './' + $(this).data('tooltipsrc');
                    console.log(tooltip_url);
                    $.get(tooltip_url, {},
                          function(data) {
                              callback(data);
                          });
                }  // ... content option
            });  // ... tooltip
         });  // ... document ready
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- HTML -->
      <p>
         <span data-tooltipsrc="snippet1.html"
               class="tooltip"
               title="ignored">
            Tooltip text from <a href="snippet1.html">snippet1.html</a>
         </span>
      </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is the content of `snippet1.html` (I tried it without the html and body first, but it made no difference):

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>Snippet 1</h1>
    <p>Tooltip text from <tt>snippet1.html</tt></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

However, I have seen the `console.log` firing (in one of my attempts), but I have never seen the content of `snippet1.html` in use; the best I got was an empty tooltip.

I have tested the `$(document).ready` part with a modified example with static html for the `content`; this works.

I've tried all sorts of

- `$.get(tooltip_url);`
- `$.get(tooltip_url, response);`
- `$.get(tooltip_url, {}, response);`
- `return $.get(tooltip_url, {}, response);`
- `return $.get(tooltip_url);`

... and finally gave up.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3rc93h5d/1/ - looks fine

Comment: check to see whether the ajx request is completed successfully

Comment: You need to check this on a server. If you are trying the code locally it will not work. As per jQuery documentation for get() *Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request.* :)

Comment: I can't see anything in the Firebug networks tab (only requests to get the library resources).

Comment: @BojanPetkovski: Indeed, now it works ... (I somewhat had the idea that browsers might be smart enough to replace a GET request to a local resource by a reading filesystem access). If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: As far as I could see, the fiddle doesn't use the contents of `snippet.html` but the mere url - which is not what I need(ed) ...

Comment: Someone downvoted my question, and I have no idea about the reason ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check this on a server. If you are trying the code locally it will not work. As per jQuery documentation for get() *Load data from the server using a HTTP GET request.* :)

PS: Glad that I could help :)